# Display image through mustache template

Tags: javascript, json, nested, mustache

```
 "<p><strong> Creator: </strong> {{#creator}}{{name}}  <img src="{{avatarUrl}}" alt="avatar"> {{/creator}}</p>" +
```

I have created a web application which pulls JSON data from a REST api and displays this data on my web page.

Whilst using the Mustache template I am having issues displaying images via a URL given in the JSON data. The rest of the data displays on the web page.

I have embedded the variable within the image tags which can be seen attached. It seems to be an issue once quoting the variable.

avatarURL is a nested variable, relating to the variable "creator".

Can anyone explain how I can get the images to display?

Comment: This seems to be a straightforward case. Did you verify your image URL by accessing it directly? If you are giving relative path please check that as well.

Comment: Yes the URL is accessible directly, and I have checked the relative path.
When I enter the image tag, and run the application, there isn't any data that shows at all.

Comment: Have you tried with triple braces `{{{avatarUrl}}}` or `{{& avatarUrl}}`? If that doesn't work please include the html it's creating now, so it is easier to see what the problem might be